# App pool time outs CRL checks

Tags: central-administration

I am running SharePoint 2010 Enterprise sp1 April 2012 CU on a farm without internet connectivity.

After every IIS reset the app pool takes forever to spin up.  I have tried pointing the following urls to loopback to remedy this but to no avail it still takes a very long time for the CRL check to time out.

127.0.0.1  crl.microsoft.com
127.0.0.1  crl.verisign.com
127.0.0.1  ocsp.verisign.com
127.0.0.1  SVRSecure-G2-crl.verisign.com
127.0.0.1  SVRSecure-G3-crl.verisign.com
127.0.0.1  www.download.windowsupdate.com
127.0.0.1  SVRSecure-G2-aia.verisign.com

I have also been getting a correlation ID when trying to access any site for the first time following an iisreset and clicking "back to site" brings the site up which makes me think its taking so long for the app pool to spin up that it times out the first time.

Has anoyone else been able to resolve these issues with the CRL check timeouts?  This is happening in more than one farm with the same configuration.

Comment: This is all that's in the ULS logs:  

12/05/2013 12:34:44.82  w3wp.exe (0x0DE0)                        0x0E70 SharePoint Foundation          Monitoring                     nasq Medium   Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://hostname:9600/default.aspx))  
12/05/2013 12:34:44.82  w3wp.exe (0x0DE0)                        0x0E70 SharePoint Foundation          Logging Correlation Data       xmnv Medium   Name=Request (GET:http://hostname:9600/default.aspx) e252e2a5-1cb1-4f70-afa7-1031f95258e7

Comment: Well, have you had success resolving your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the CRL to your hosts file won't do much good. It is much better to disable the Certificate Revocation List checking by using this powershell script:

```
set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WinTrust\Trust Providers\Software Publishing" -name State -value 146944

set-ItemProperty -path "REGISTRY::\HKEY_USERS\.Default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WinTrust\Trust Providers\Software Publishing" -name State -value 146944

get-ChildItem REGISTRY::HKEY_USERS | foreach-object {set-ItemProperty -ErrorAction silentlycontinue -path ($_.Name + "\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WinTrust\Trust Providers\Software Publishing")  -name State -value 146944}

Write-Host -ForegroundColor White "Disabling CRL check..."
ForEach($bitsize in ("","64")) 
{           
  $xml = [xml](Get-Content $env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework$bitsize\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Machine.config)
  If (!$xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("runtime")) { 
    $runtime = $xml.CreateElement("runtime")
    $xml.DocumentElement.AppendChild($runtime) | Out-Null
  }
  If (!$xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("runtime/generatePublisherEvidence")) {
    $gpe = $xml.CreateElement("generatePublisherEvidence")
    $xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("runtime").AppendChild($gpe)  | Out-Null
  }
  $xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("runtime/generatePublisherEvidence").SetAttribute("enabled","false")  | Out-Null
  $xml.Save("$env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework$bitsize\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Machine.config")
}
```

Comment: Ok I have seen that around before just never tested it I'll give it a shot.  Do the host file entries need to stay once this is done or does that do everything I need?

Comment: Well, since the CRL checks will not be performed, and you don't have access to the internet anyway, I would say you are free to do whatever you please with those hosts entries... ;)